# How to modify css attribute without using javascript in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Is there a way to modify css attribute without using selenium's driver.execute_script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not.

Selenium is meant to mimic user interactions with the browser.  Setting CSS attributes is not part of the normal user interaction with a browser.

If you wish to modify a CSS attribute, you will need to use `execute-script`.